# Calculating median values in HIVE

Tags: statistics, hive, hiveql, median, percentile

I have the following table t1:

```
key  value
 1   38.76
 1   41.19
 1   42.22
 2   29.35182
 2   28.32192
 3   33.66
 3   33.47
 3   33.35
 3   33.47
 3   33.11
 3   32.98
 3   32.5
```

I want to compute the median for each key group. According to the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF), the percentile_approx function should work for this. The median values for each group are:

```
1  41.19
2  28.83
3  33.35
```

However, the percentile_approx function returns these:

```
1  39.974999999999994
2  28.32192
3  33.23.0000000000004
```

Which clearly are not the median values.

This was the query I ran:

```
select key, percentile_approx(value, 0.5, 10000) as median
from t1
group by key
```

It seems to be not taking into account one value per group, resulting in a wrong median. Ordering does not affect the result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Hive, median cannot be calculated directly by using available built-in functions. Below query is used to find the median.

```
    set hive.exec.parallel=true;
    select temp1.key,temp2.value
    from 
      (
      select key,cast(sum(rank)/count(key) as int) as final_rank
      from
        (
        select key,value,
        row_number() over (partition by key order by value) as rank
        from t1
      ) temp
      group by key )temp1
    inner join
    ( select key,value,row_number() over (partition by key order by value) as rank
      from t1  )temp2
       on 
       temp1.key=temp2.key and
       temp1.final_rank=temp3.rank;
```

Above query finds the row_number for each key by ordering the values for the key. Finally it will take the middle row_number of each key which gives the median value. Also I have added one more parameter **"hive.exec.parallel=true;"** which enables to run the independent tasks in parallel.

Comment: How does this deal with the scenario when there is an even number of values? Also why are you grouping by key in the first part when you aren't using any aggregate functions @Nithiyanandhan

Comment: I have edited my answer. First part will order the values based on key and find the middle row number , second part will find the row number for each key. By joining first result and second result , we will get the median for the key. This will also the even number scenario.